# SQL get login and Logout timestamp

Tags: sql, group-by

Is this possible in SQL command.

```
TABLE

ID|USERID|TIMESTAMP           |ACTION|
1 |USER1 |8/23/2013 3:25:10 PM|LOGOUT|
2 |USER1 |8/23/2013 3:15:10 PM|LOGIN |
3 |USER1 |8/23/2013 1:25:10 PM|LOGIN |
4 |USER2 |8/23/2013 9:25:10 AM|LOGOUT|
5 |USER2 |8/23/2013 8:25:10 AM|LOGIN |
```

Result:

```
USERID|TIMESTAMP LOGIN     |TIMESTAMP LOGOUT    
USER1 |8/23/2013 3:15:10 PM|8/23/2013 3:25:10 PM
USER1 |8/23/2013 1:25:10 PM|
USER2 |8/23/2013 8:25:10 AM|8/23/2013 9:25:10 AM
```

Basically I need to get the login date and time of the user.  There are cases there is no logout entry due to the user clicks x button instead of clicks the logout button.

Thanks,
Ryl

Comment: cant you handle it on frontend?

Comment: Cannot change the given table. Only use SQL to format the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you use MS SQL server in case of MySQL remove `TOP 1` and add `LIMIT 1` to the end of the subquery:

```
select ID,USERID,TIMESTAMP as LOGIN_TIME,
(SELECT TOP 1 
        CASE WHEN ACTION='LOGOUT' 
            THEN TIMESTAMP
            ELSE NULL
        END

        FROM T
        WHERE USERID=T1.USERID
              AND
              TIMESTAMP>T1.TIMESTAMP
        ORDER BY TIMESTAMP
) AS LOGOUT_TIME

from T AS T1
WHERE ACTION='LOGIN'
ORDER BY ID
```

[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f73d8/12)